# Can you use ROS to save images to PCD?

Tags: openni, pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All of the search results I find for interaction for ROS and PCL are a few years old.  I'm curious if there is a way to save PCD files from Kinect streams directly by a ROS input.  Let's assume that the Kinects are launched through the standard openni.launch approach with names kinect_1 and Kinect_2. Would I be able to take "snapshots" of the stream and then use that data for a PCD file and PCL applications?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149771/can-you-use-ros-to-save-images-to-pcd?/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I´m not aware of any official implementation, but writing a small node(let) that does this should be pretty easy. In [this Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/121856/write-pcd-file-from-a-topic-hydro-pcl-migration/) something very close to what you want to do is discussed (along with code).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1